# WPF. Часть текста Title изменить шрифт на Bold

Tags: c#, wpf

У формы есть заголовок окна Title. Мне нужно назвать приложение например: Приложение организации Тест, слово тест выделить жирным.
Приложение организации **Тест**
Каким образом такое можно сделать? Знаю если бы нужно было сделать для Label такое, то не проблема, Textblock в нем добавляем Inlin'ы и присваиваем Label то что получилось. Но в Title такое не прокатывает. Может кто сталкивался?

Comment: Ну это как бы нестандартное поведение, вам нужен нестандартный заголовок окна...

Comment: С нестандартным поведением, это я понимаю. Но как сделать нестандартный заголовок окна? может у вас есть пример?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Неклиентскую область окна можно изменить применив нестандартный `WindowChrome`, например это может выглядеть как-то так:

```
<Window ...>
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <!--Меняем WindowChrome-->
        <WindowChrome GlassFrameThickness="{x:Static WindowChrome.GlassFrameCompleteThickness}"/>
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <Window.Template>
        <!--Меняем шаблон окна-->
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="c:MainWindow">
            <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!--Одна строка для заголовка-->
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <!--Одна для контента-->
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <!--Заголовок-->
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="7,7,7,0">
                    <!--Вернем иконку на место-->
                    <Image Source="{Binding Icon, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                           Width="16" Height="16" Margin="0,0,4,0"/>
                    <!--Собственно текст заголовка, теперь его нужно редактировать здесь-->
                    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        Special for <Run FontWeight="Bold">stackoverflow</Run>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>

                <!--Контент будет вставляться сюда-->
                <Border Grid.Row="1" Margin="7" BorderBrush="Black"
                        BorderThickness="1" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Template>

    <!--Ну а здесь уже идет обычный контент, который вы помещаете в окно-->
    <Grid Margin="5">
        <TextBlock Text="Some text"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ответ подготовлен на основании этого мануала: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsdk/2010/08/25/experiments-with-windowchrome/

`WindowChrome` начиная с .NET 4.5 часть PresentationFramework.dll, поэтому подключать дополнительно ничего не требуется.

---

Для того, чтобы вернуть системное меню при клике по иконке окна, нужно превратить ее в кнопку (замените в разметке `Image` на этот фрагмент):

```
                    <Button Margin="0,0,4,0" Click="ShowSystemMenu">
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <ContentPresenter/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Icon, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                               Width="16" Height="16" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True"/>
                    </Button>
```

и написать в codebehind обработчик клика следующего содержания:

```
private void ShowSystemMenu(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var source = (FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource;
    var locationFromScreen = source.PointToScreen(new Point(0, source.ActualHeight));
    var presentationSource = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);
    var targetPoint = presentationSource.CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice.Transform(locationFromScreen);
    SystemCommands.ShowSystemMenu(this, targetPoint);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Но имейте ввиду, что отображение на разных ОС может значительно отличаться, надо тестировать поведение на разных ОС с разными темами. Впрочем, это относится ко всему GUI :)