# C# WPF окно больше монитора когда maximized

Tags: c#, wpf

```
<WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
    <WindowChrome
    x:Name="windowchrome"
    CaptionHeight="0"
    ResizeBorderThickness="5" />
</WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
```

и

```
WindowStyle="None"
```

получилось вот так в углу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вот не пойму как Google сделали [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 и вкладки в title bar'e в Google Chrome? Похоже окно дефолтное но они залезли в title bar... как?

Comment: [WPF: Нестандартное окно](https://habr.com/post/158561/)

Comment: Установите `GlassFrameThickness="-1"` для того чтобы показать дефолтные кнопки в заголовке: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809390/218063

Answer (score 0):

Для решения проблемы можно использовать [этот](https://github.com/Minorsonek/Quiz-WPF/blob/master/Quiz/Window/WindowResizer.cs) вспомогательный класс. Достаточно передать в конструктор нужное окно, в паре с WindowChrome будет работать как родное.