# Максимальное разрешение экрана

Tags: c#, wpf

Сделал свою шапку для окна, и хочу добавить туда стандартные кнопки "свернуть", "развернуть", и "закрыть". Всё как бы хорошо, но при развертывании на весь экран съедается меню пуск и видно как по периметру уходит на пару пикселей со всех сторон. Как можно это исправить? Возможно кто-то сталкивался?

```
Title="Работа с пользователями" Height="700" Width="1300" MinHeight="700" MinWidth="1300" 
        WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"

    <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="Transparent" MouseLeftButtonDown="UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonDown">
        <materialDesign:ColorZone Mode="Inverted">
            <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                    <Button Width="20" Height="20" Padding="0" Background="Purple" Click="But_min_au_OnClick" Margin="5">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="WindowMinimize" Foreground="White"/>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Width="20" Height="20" Padding="0" Background="Purple" Click="But_max_au_OnClick" Margin="5">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="WindowMaximize" Foreground="White"/>
                    </Button>
                    <Button Width="20" Height="20" Padding="0" Background="Purple" Click="But_close_au_OnClick" Margin="5">
                        <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="WindowClose" Foreground="White"/>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >

                    <TextBlock Text="Работа с пользователями" FontSize="15" Margin="5"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DockPanel>
        </materialDesign:ColorZone>
    </Border>



    private void But_max_au_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
            WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        else
            WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/831355/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP бесполезная ссылка, там нет ответа

Comment: А полезная есть?

Comment: @ЕвгенийШалаев, там есть комментарии с полезными ссылками. Ну и ТС не правильно действует, нужно действовать через WindowChrome. В любом случае вы можете написать хороший правильный ответ.