# Window выходит за пределы монитора

Tags: wpf

Обратил внимание, что у окна выходит кусочек на другой монитор.

Почему так ?

Левый верхний угол основного монитора по `GetPosition` 7,7

Правый нижний угол основного монитора по `GetPosition` 1926,1086

в XAML:

```
    Title="Window1" Height="450" Width="800"
    WindowStyle="None"
    WindowState="Maximized"
    AllowsTransparency="True"
```

Это какие то особенности или где то косяк ?

Просто странно что при открытии этого окна, торчит кусок на другом мониторе(

Comment: Связанный вопроc: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/831355/c-wpf-окно-больше-монитора-когда-maximized?rq=1

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight не уловил связь( - Как то лечится ? Или стоит ручками получать размеры и присваивать окну чтобы ни откуда не вылезало ?

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Данную проблемы заметил просто играясь. А цель - сделать прозрачное окно без рамок расширяющееся на все мониторы если расширен рабочий стол.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Перетаскивания не нужны, ResizeMode = "NoResize" Действительно помог. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На основе обсуждения в комментариях:

По непонятным причинам, связка свойств `WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True"` ведет себя некорректно, когда ResizeMode отличен от "NoResize". Если изменение размеров окна перетаскиванием не нужно, достаточно установить `ResizeMode = "NoResize"`, окно перестает вылезать за пределы монитора при максимизации. Если нужно, то что-то одно - либо изменение размеров перетаскиванием, либо подгонку размера окна под границы монитора при максимизации - придется реализовать вручную.