# Отключить масштабирование приложения

Tags: c#, wpf

Подскажите пожалуйста как в c# wpf vs2010 отключить масштабирование окон и всех элементов в зависимости от изменения размера экрана. Т.е. я создаю приложение (окна и элементы окна) при размере экрана 100%, и если у пользователя размер экрана иной, например, 125% - то мое приложение должно отображаться как в оригинале (т.е. как при 100%). Сейчас если я запускаю приложение при 125%, то оно как-будто увеличивается кратно. Ниже привожу пример кода xaml для первого окна:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Test" Height="209" Width="350" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Background="#FFE0E0E0" FontFamily="Arial" FontSize="9">
    <Grid Width="350" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource MyButton1}" Content="Выход" Height="37" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,128,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="140" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="14" IsTabStop="False" Click="button2_Click" Background="LightGray"></Button>
        <Label Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="102,14,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Content="Test" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="18" Width="120" />
        <Separator Height="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="9,93,9,0" Name="separator1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="322" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Пользователь, наверное, не просто так себе масштаб увеличил, вы же создадите неудобство для него лишнее

Comment: Дело в том, что в масштабе 125% окно приложения не помещается в границы монитора.

Comment: Ну это понятно, вы же "рисуете контролы мышкой", отсюда и все эти ваши `Margin="102,14,0,0"`. Пишите разметку вручную и по максимуму используйте доступные в WPF панели.

Comment: Имейте ввиду, что помимо масштабирования у пользователей еще могут быть разномастные мониторы, от самых распространенных ноутбучных 1366x768 до современных 4K, а так же с разным соотношением сторон (да, в корпоративном сегменте до сих **очень** много старых квадратных мониторов)

Comment: А можно ли кодом сделать: что если размер 125% - то задать какой-то коэффициент уменьшения?

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста ключевую фразу (как масштабировать кодом), чтобы почитать в интернете?

Comment: Вы не знаете как получить текущий масштаб Windows или как изменить масштаб контролов?

Comment: Как изменить масштаб окна и всех контролов на нем, чтобы было как при 100% (как при масштабе в котором конструирую приложение). Подскажите, как зная значение размера экрана - заставить изменить размер окна и всех контролов?

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в конструктор окна (после `InitializeComponent`):

```
// Узнаем текущий масштаб Windows
var scaleX = VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this).DpiScaleX;
var scaleY = VisualTreeHelper.GetDpi(this).DpiScaleY;
// Трансформируем контент окна до масштаба 100%
((UIElement)Content).RenderTransform = new ScaleTransform(1 / scaleX, 1 / scaleY);
```

Если у вас .NET ниже версии 4.6.2, то этот метод не сработает. Попробуйте так, но имейте ввиду, что это сработает только после того, как окно будет загружено (например, в подписчике на `Loaded`):

```
var scaleX = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M11;
var scaleY = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this).CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.M22;
```

Comment: GetDpi ошибка: System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper не содержит определение для "GetDpi"?

Comment: .NET 4.6.2 или выше требуется

Comment: я использую 4.0. Не возможно?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо! Это работает но только для контролов окна. Подскажите пожалуйста, как заставить масштабировать само окно?

Comment: Автоматически никак, только если рисовать кастомный заголовок. Но я вам рекомендую всерьез задуматься об адаптивном дизайне

Comment: "только если рисовать кастомный заголовок"? - можете пояснить подробнее? или где прочитать?

Comment: Например, как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809390/218063