# C# WPF Заливка части Grid цветом под UI элементом (слоем ниже)

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать без MahApps этот эффект нижнего слоя? Заливка ниже UI элементов, как оно работает? Буду рад примерам.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [WPF. Часть текста Title изменить шрифт на Bold](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/809329/wpf-%d0%a7%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-title-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%88%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-bold)

Comment: Используете mahApps? Это из их примером или ваш код?

Comment: @UporotayaPanda да, mahApps, пример не мой

Comment: @MikeWaters из того, что я бы попробовал первоначально - добавить Flyouts из библиотеки MahApps с параметром прозрачности.

Comment: @MikeWaters но более "красивым" решением я считаю применение Flyouts не ко всему окну, а только к контенту основного окна.