# Изменить цвет строки состояния

Tags: c#, wpf

Как в приложении wpf изменить цвет строки состояния(панели на которой расположны кнопки "свернуть" "маштабировать" "закрыть")? Например чтобы она была не белой а черной.

Comment: Вы что то не то подразумеваете под строкой состояния, вам наверное будет лучше картинку приложить, чтобы было всем ясно, что вам нужно сделать

Comment: Как-то так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809390/218063

Comment: Это называется не строка состояния, а хром (неклиентская область окна). Для изменения хрома придётся переопределить шаблон окна и самостоятельно указать нужный цвет.

Comment: При этом нужно будет самостоятельно нарисовать системные кнопочки.