# Как изменить цвет верхней границы модального окна в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Чтобы убрать иконку у окна установил свойство `WindowStyle="ToolWindow"`, но после этого у окна появился верхний `border` чёрного цвета.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На картинке показана верхняя часть окна на сером фоне. Подскажите, плс, как сделать фон `border`'a цветом окна или окно обвести в `border` чёрного цвета?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Guess.Yourself.AboutGuessYourself"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:Guess.Yourself"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="О программе &quot;Угадай себя&quot;" 
        Height="320" Width="450"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        WindowStyle="ToolWindow">
     <Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Либо через [Chrome](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809390/220553) попробовать, либо полностью [переписать окно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1011208/220553).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ через Chrome, откуда там кнопки берутся?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ И что такое `TargetType="c:MainWindow"`?

Comment: А они там не переопределяются, через хром это по сути вы рисуете новым слоем поверх существующего (тот, который уже имеет кнопки). Вот например я сделал простой `Border` с половиной прозрачности и красным цветом, как [видите](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfk0K.png) он идет поверх существующих кнопок как отдельный слой. `TargetType="c:MainWindow"` - это к какому типу применяется шаблон, там должно быть скорей всего просто `TargetType="{x:Type local:MainWindow}"`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо, получилось сделать, то что хотелось с помощью первого примера, но осталось ряд вопросов. Объявив в разметке `WindowChrome` - мы сказали, что будет слой, где использовано св-во `GlassFrameThickness` - что оно даёт? И дальше, получается, просто переопределили шаблон окна?

Comment: Почитайте в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.shell.windowchrome?view=netcore-3.1#windowchrome).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ок, спс)