# Где можно найти стандартные иконки кнопок заголовка окна(свернуть, развернуть на часть экрана/на весь экран, закрыть)

Tags: wpf

Я пишу программу с помощью wpf api, и мне надо переопределить заголовок окна, однако я хочу оставить кнопки (свернуть, развернуть на часть экрана/на весь экран, закрыть).
Если есть простое программное решение, то это мне тоже подойдёт, а так я хочу достать иконки кнопок для решения этой задачи.

[image: Изображение кнопок] Вот так они выглядят, если что.

Comment: А что мешает вам взять векторную графику и использовать ее?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809390/218063