Как изменить верхнюю панель окна WPF C#
Возможно ли добавлять/редактировать элементы верхней панели окна, как на фото ниже в WPF?


https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/809390/220553

Или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/676221/10105
